# Why is nodemailer sending duplicate emails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

So this is a very odd question and I don't expect any one to really have an answer to this, but I'm here to try and see if anyone has experienced the same issue.

The issue that I'm noticing is that our application seems to be sending duplicate emails.  For example, I can send a report from our application, and it will send that email once, and then it looks like another one gets sent exactly a minute later.

I'm using `nodemailer` to send the emails from our applications server, and our default email that we use in our office is `Outlook v16.0.12130.20272` using **IMAP**.  These emails are being sent by our **noreply** email which I believe is being hosted through **GoDaddy**.

I've sent test emails myself and looked in the network tab to see if it might be a timeout issue, but the response completes with a `200 OK status` and the timing shows up as completed as well.  Also when I console log the response it only occurs once, which makes me believe that it is actually only sending one email. There must be something happening in between when the host sends the email, and when our recipients actually receive them, but I'm not quite sure.

Here is the **server.js** file.  This is where the `smtp` request is being made.

```js
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')



import env from '../env.config.json';

const PORT = require('../env.config.json').SERVER.PORT;
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
import api from './routers/api-routing';
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: env.EMAIL.SERVICE,
    host: env.EMAIL.HOST,
    auth: {
        user:env.EMAIL.AUTH.USER,
        pass:env.EMAIL.AUTH.PASS
    }
});

var mailCounter = 0;
var numPeople = 0;

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
const port = PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

const io = socketIO(server);
app.use('/api', api(app, io));
// require('./routers/api-routing')(app, io);
//$.get("/send", { to: to, subject: subject).value, text: 'html' }, function (data) { });
app.get('*', function (request, response) {
    if (request.get('x-auth')) console.log("x-auth: ", request.get('x-auth'));
    const proto = request.get('X-Forwarded-Proto');
    if (proto) {
        if (proto === 'http') response.redirect(301, "https://ourdomain.com".concat(request.url));
    }
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'public', 'index.html'))
    if ((request.url).substring(0, 5) == "/send") {
        var mailOptions = {
            to: request.query.to,
            bcc: request.query.bcc,
            subject: request.query.subject,
            text: request.query.text
        }
        //console.log(mailOptions); Read up on NodeMailer for details.
        smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
            from: "COMPANY <noreply@ouremail.com>", // sender address.  Must be the same as authenticated user if using Gmail.
            to: mailOptions.to,
            bcc: "COMPANY <noreply@ouremail.com>",    // sending to itself
            subject: mailOptions.subject, // subject
            html: mailOptions.text, // body
        }, function (error, response) {  //callback
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log("Message sent");
               //console.log("Amount of people getting this email: " + response.accepted.length);
            }

            smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages.  Comment this line out to continue sending emails.
        });
    }

});



io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    require('./middleware/sockets')(socket);


});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}.`);
});
```

This is the part of our env.config.file that pertains to the emails.

```js
"EMAIL": {
    "SERVICE": "Godaddy",
    "HOST": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "AUTH": {
      "USER": "noreply@ouremail.com",
      "PASS": "OURPASS"
    }
  }
```

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I would be very appreciative, thanks!

Comment: Is the ReactJS tag required here?

Comment: probably not, I just removed it.

Comment: I have faced this same issue (Duplicate mail after exactly a minute). I fixed it by explicitly adding 'status(200)' to the response. Let me know if it works!

Comment: The code is using a lot of dif techniques to import libraries, just a suggestion to try and unify that. Also you're sending a redirect but allowing the rest of the script to run, that could be an issue. The 60 seconds makes me think a request is timing out and hitting a URL again or something. You're also listening for all GET requests (`*`), I'd limit that to the routes that you want this code to actually run on. Finally, are you positive you're only seeing the console output in your *node* app 1 time? If that's the case, check GoDaddy. Perhaps your BCCing noreply causes an auto-reply?

Comment: @Krishna you're saying put response.status(200) inside that else statement?

Comment: I'm talking about `response.status(200).sendFile` @Michael

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser I totally agree with what you're saying here.  This isn't my code, this was there before I was hired into this job.  And yes I am positive, I only see "Message Sent" once from my server.

Comment: @Krishna Ok but should I put that within the else statement? Or where are you saying this needs to go?

Comment: @Michael just replace the line `response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'public', 'index.html'))` by adding status(200)

Comment: @Krishna Ok gotcha, will try this.

Comment: @Krishna - `.sendFile()` already sets the status to 200 if you don't set it yourself.  Setting it to 200 is not necessary.

Comment: I don't know about `.sendFile()` but when i faced this same issue, i was using `.send(someJSON)` and even though it was returning status(200), mentioning explicitly solved my issue. Just wanted him try it out to see if it works for him too. @jfriend00

Comment: @Krishna - I don't know what to say.  Specifying no status with `.sendFile()` uses the default 200 status.  It just does.  There is no need to specify a 200 status.  Your situation must have had something else involved in the problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes I know. But i have verified that if I remove `status(200)` in my code, it starts to send duplicates again. Clearly, explicit mention fixes it. Also, it happens 'exactly' after a minute (not a second more or less). What do you think?  .I not sure if your 'favicon.ico second request' explains that fixed interval gap.

Comment: @Krishna I still get duplicate emails doing it your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I have finally figured out the reason for this behavior.  The issue is partially related to what `jfriend00` had posted.  I ended up making a separate route handler for the emails themselves so that it didn't interfere with the main route handler.  The problem is that every request will still go through that route since it is looking for any request indicated by the `*` and if a person is on the http route making the request instead of https, then it creates a second request or in my case a second email.

You can see that happening in this line here:

```
if (proto) {
        if (proto === 'http') response.redirect(301, "https://ourdomain.com".concat(request.url));
    }
```

The actual fix for this was to create a separate route handler for the emails themselves and then configure my `nginx` server to reroute to https if a person was going to the http route of the application instead.  After this, we have not experienced anymore duplicate emails.

Another way of doing it would be to remove the ```*```` route handler completely and setup the other routes separately.  Hopefully this will help somebody in the near future.

Answer (score 6):

Your email is being sent on any request sent to your server so if you access it via a browser, the browser will send two requests, one for the path requested and one for the favicon.ico and you're also sending an email when `/favicon.ico` is requested.

This can happen because you're route handler is configured as:

```
app.get('*', ...);
```

That means you're attempting to send an email for every single incoming http request regardless of path.

So, if you go to your host with a browser at `http://yourdomain/`, it will first request `/` and then the browser will request `/favicon.ico`, causing you to then send a second email.

My suggestion is to change from this:

```
app.get('*', ...);
```

to this:

```
app.get('/', ...);
```

or, even more specific such as:

```
app.get('/sendemail', ...);
```

So, you are only sending the email on one specific path request and it will not send the email no other requests such as the favicon.  You probably want to add a generic express 404 handler for any other routes.

---

Note: In a REST design, you would probably send an email with a POST request, not a GET request.  A GET would retrieve a resource in a read-only kind of way that does not change any state so it wouldn't have a side effect of sending an email.  Note: this isn't related to your problem at all, just a comment about a typical REST design.

Comment: These are very good points.  I should have also mentioned that the duplicate email thing hasn't always happened.  It didn't happen until just recently, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Michael - Why not fix this issue and see if the problem goes away?  I can't speak to how an earlier version of your code behaved.  Several things could have changed enabling this problem to now occur.

Comment: Yep I'm working on that, I just wanted to point that out, that's all.

Comment: @Michael - You can see the effect of fixing this by just changing `"*"` to `"/"`.

Comment: @jfriend00 `browser will send two requests` - why do you think there is a minute delay between these requests?

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry been super busy, will try today and see if this works.  If not I feel like the email from GoDaddy is saving them, and this could be why they are sending twice.

Comment: @Michael - Did this answer your question? If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure. If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.

Comment: this did not work, I think it doesn't actually have anything to do with the code itself but with the host email.  Some days it seems to send single emails, and others it ends up sending duplicates.  This doesn't seem like a code related issue anymore.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've converted our emails to send through AWS SES now, and I'm going to use that with your suggestion to see if that solves the issue.